# React native async storage issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

In my react native app I am trying to save data into my local storage. It works fine most of the time but sometime I get error while setting the item.

So here is the code for me setting the item

```
async setString(key: string, value: any) {
    try {
      return await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch (e) {
      LogService.logError(
        'apiClient',
        'apptype',
        `Error setting local storage, key: ${key} error: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`,
      )
    }
  }
```

1. One of the thing is that my error doesn't prints.
2. IOS users are having this issues
3. Do I need to first delete the item and then write to it? Doesn't setString override the value?
4. Is there any storage problem on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse()` when getting and `JSON.stringify()` when setting it

Comment: I use that in case of objects. But these are just strings.

Comment: @mohsinali1317 what error showing in `catch` block? can you show that

Comment: That is the issue, it doesn't show any error at all.

Comment: @mohsinali1317 what are you sending params in it? please share

Answer (score 0):

**It's worked for me, you can try this.**

```
useEffect(() => {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('isLaunched').then((value) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('isLaunched', 'true'); // No need to wait for `setItem` to finish, although you might want to handle errors
    }); // Add some error handling, also you can simply do 

}, []);
```